# Entityframework core how to map Many-to-Many without creating a join table

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying this activity to clone from existing .edmx project to code first.

I have two entities. I want to have many to many relation without creating a new table. I am using EF Core 2.0 code first approach.

Please find below the entity i have created. I am not sure whether is this is the right way to do this.

I would like to have the foreign key column on both the tables ie. WorkflowId and WorkCaseId on WorkCase and Workflow tables respectively.

```
    public class WorkCase
    {
        [Key]
        public int WorkCaseId { get; set; }

        public int WorkflowId { get; set; }

        public int CaseDetailId {get;set;}

        public CaseDetail CaseDetail {get;set;}

        public WorkFlow WorkFlow { get; set; }

        public ICollection<WorkFlow> WorkFlows { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkFlow : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int WorkFlowId { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public int WorkCaseId { get; set; }

        public WorkCase WorkCase { get; set; }

        public ICollection<WorkCase> WorkCases { get; set; }
    }
```

My expectation is as below. Can anyone help how to achieve the EF Core configuration:
- Workcase will have the latest workflowid
- workflow will have history for each workcaseid.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: [EF Core documentation - Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) Note the following paragraph *"Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported."*

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you. I have updated my query with my expectation. Can you help me how to map to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: EF5+ supports many-to-many without explicitly mapping the join table. See [this EF announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many)
As commented on your question, EF Core <= 2.2 [does not yet support many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) without a join table. This is an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368) tracked in the EF Core repo's backlock, and will maybe [make it into version 3.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508#issuecomment-389922109).

In your case you'll need to introduce a new table that relates to both parent tables. In this case, your model will like something like the following:

```
public class WorkCase
{
    public int WorkCaseId { get; set; }

    public int CaseDetailId { get; set; }

    public CaseDetail CaseDetail { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkCaseWorkflow> Workflows { get; set; }
}

public class Workflow
{
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkCaseWorkflow> WorkCases { get; set; }
}

public class WorkCaseWorkflow
{
    public int WorkCaseId { get; set; }
    public WorkCase WorkCase { get; set; }

    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `DbContext` subclass, override the `OnModelCreating` and add the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    var ww = builder.Entity<WorkCaseWorkflow>();
    ww.HasKey(w => new { w.WorkCaseId, WorkflowId });
    ww.HasOne(w => w.WorkCase)
      .WithMany(wc => wc.Workflows)
      .HasForeignKey(w => w.WorkCaseId);
    ww.HasOne(w => w.Workflow)
      .WithMany(wc => wc.WorkCases)
      .HasForeignKey(w => w.WorkflowId);
}
```

I'm not familiar with your model, but you can move the shared properties to the join table.

---

However, there is a great series of articles by [@Arthur Vickers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012410/arthur-vickers) (a member in the EF Core dev team) on how to easen up many-to-many relationships:

- [Part 1: The basics](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-1-the-basics/)
- [Part 2: Hiding as IEnumerable](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-2-hiding-as-ienumerable/)
- [Part 3: Hiding as ICollection](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-3-hiding-as-icollection/)
- [Part 4: A more general abstraction](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/)