# How to configure Many to One relationship?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently I'm working on a Rest api in dotnet core with a Mysql Database. At the moment I have two Tables with Users and roles. For my project I need to get the user and the role. In my code I pecified the relationships as stated in this Sample

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
private void InitEntityRole(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
    {
         entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("Id");
         entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("naam");
    });
}

private void InitEntityUser(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("Id");
        entity.Property(e => e.Username).HasColumnName("gebruikersnaam");
        entity.Property(e => e.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("wachtwoord");
        entity.Property(e => e.PasswordSalt).HasColumnName("salt");
        entity.HasOne(u => u.Person)
            .WithOne(p => p.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Person>(p => p.Id)
            .HasConstraintName("fk_persoon");
        entity.HasOne(u => u.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.Id)
            .HasConstraintName("fk_gebruikerrol");
      });
}
```

In my code I have a test function to retrieve all users like this

```
public List<User> GetAll()
{
    var users = _dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Role).ToList();
    users.ForEach(u => u.Password = null);

    return users;
}
```

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DamstraChallengeBackend.Models
{
    [Table("rol")]
    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;    
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DamstraChallengeBackend.Models
{
    [Table("gebruiker")]
    public class User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Token { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My tables are configured ass followed

User:

```
CREATE TABLE `gebruiker` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `gebruikersnaam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `wachtwoord` blob NOT NULL,
   `salt` blob NOT NULL,
   `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    KEY `fk_persoon` (`p_id`),
    KEY `fk_gebruikerrol` (`r_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_gebruikerrol` FOREIGN KEY (`r_id`) REFERENCES `rol` (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_persoon` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `persoon` (`Id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Role:

```
CREATE TABLE `rol` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

When I execute this code, all I get is an empty array. I think that I made an error in the cofiguration but I can't seem to find it. Please could anyone help me.

The things I tried are: Leaving out the include and then I get an array with users without there roles. But as soon as I add the include statement nothing shows up.

The thing I find curious is that it worked when I had one user with a group. As soon as I add more all I get is an empty array.

I apologize for the errors in my English but I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: In this line `users.ForEach(u => u.Password = null);` change to `users.ForEach(u => u.Password == null);`

Comment: @pnet might be worth emphasizing "*`==` instead of `=`*" (took me several seconds to find what was different ;) )

Comment: All that line does is changing the password field to zero. I'm sorry it was from an early iteration of my code. But removing it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Added a working sample solution with in-memory-db-context on [github](https://github.com/alsami/Stackoverflow_56131817_Ef_Problem).

The relations are wrong which is probably causing entity-framework to behave that way. This is a many to many relation between the entity-type `User` and the entity-type `Role`. One user has `0..1` to `n` roles, `1` role is assigned to `0..n` users.

So what you need to do is the following

1: Add the mapping entity-type `UserRole` which contains both foreign-keys and a unique-identifier

```cs
public class UserRole
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; } 
   public int RoleId { get; set; }
   public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

2: Adjust the entity-type User

```cs
public class User 
{
   // more code probably here
   public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } // virtual keyword necessary for lazy loading, can be left out if not wanted
}
```

3: Adjust the entity-type Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } // virtual keyword necessary for lazy loading, can be left out if not wanted
}
```

4: Adjust your `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method within your `DbContext` and remove your old relationship-mapping and add the new one

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
   // existing code here
   modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
     .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
     .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
     .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
     .HasOne(ur => ur.Roles)
     .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
     .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

}
```

5: Create the new model and update the database, you probably will have to drop the existing one

6: Do the query like that if you want to include roles in your users

```cs
var usersWithRoles = context.Set<User>().Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Roles);
```

[Sadly it doesn't work yet without the mapping-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972658/5397642)

[More samples can be found here](http://*%20SOLWEB-1554:%20Energycomparison%20-%20disabled%20mpptracker%20channels%20are%20ignored)

Comment: I did as you did and created an extra table with the field Id, g_Is and r_id. Also i created the class User Role and added an collection to both user and role. in my db_context I used the same code as you. But still my code returns an empty array. It should have given me 1 record. What I added is the annotation with my tablename and the column names.

Comment: Can you upload the code on github or something like it?

Comment: I'm sorry I not allowed to give you access to the entire code but I made snipppets of the concerning files. https://gitlab.com/damstrachallenge/damstrachallengebackend/snippets I hope this is enough.

Comment: Hey mate, I update the answer with a sample solution for one-to-many and many-to-many