# Entity Framework Core Many-to-Many Implementation

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, ef-core-3.0

So Many-to-Many did not make it into .NET Core 3.0 release, bummer...

I'm aware of how to implement m:m using a join entity as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972658/980917

My question is about the model classes themselves. Consider Student & Class example:

```
Student - has ICollection<StudentClass> 

StudentClass - joining entity

Class - has ICollection<StudentClass>
```

That is fine for data loading purposes. But in your business logic collection of StudentClasses is not useful as its just a joining entity with 2 IDs. When working with **Student** or **Class** you actually want an actual collection of **Classes** inside a **Student** and a collection of **Students** inside a **Class**. (ie: **Student.Classes** & **Class.Students**.

What's the current recommended approach / workaround to retrieve the many-to-many collections (not joining entity)?

Do we have to do a 2nd select based on on the joining entity or is there something more elegant?

A quick example or a link would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `What's the current recommended approach / workaround to populate those list when pulling data?`- Last part is not clear to me. Would you make it clear please?

Comment: Added more details. Basically what's the recommended approach to retrieve the many-to-many entity (not joining entity as its not useful in business logic).

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the current recommended approach / workaround to retrieve the many-to-many collections (not joining entity)?

You can do easily with `.Include` extension method as follows:

Lets say your `Student` class as follows:

```
public class Student
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string StudentName {get; set;}

  public ICollection<StudentClass> StudentClasses {get; set;}
}
```

To retrieve all the students with their associated classes:

```
var studentsWithClasses = _context.Students.Include(s => s.StudentClasses).ToList();
```

To retrieve a single student with its classes:

```
var studentWithClasses = _context.Students.Where(s => s.Id = studentId).Include(s => s.StudentClasses).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My initial concern was that in order to access Classes from Student I'd have to use Student.StudentClasses.Classes which is an annoyance. But I could easily add a Student.Classes wrapper property around that and I guess just ignore the public joining entity collection.