# Entity Framework Core: Many to Many Cascade

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble getting my head around which way to do this so asking for a bit of guidance. I have my entities set up as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972658/980917.

I have a RoleEntity, PermissionEntity and a RolePermissionsEntity. Usual set up of...

```
RoleEntity - has ICollection<PermissionEntity> 

RolePermissionEntity - joining entity

PermissionEntity - has ICollection<RoleEntity>
```

Within the OnModelBuilding I have...

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermissionEntity>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.RoleId, a.PermissionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermissionEntity>()
            .HasOne(rp => rp.Role)
            .WithMany(b => b.UserPermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.Role);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermissionEntity>()
            .HasOne(rp => rp.Permission)
            .WithMany(c => c.RolePermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PermissionId);
```

Now I know I need to add the OnDelete keyword but I can't get my head around which ones to use for what I'm after.

I'm looking to:-

- If the Role is deleted, delete the joining table and leave the permission alone.
- If the joining table entry is deleted, leave the role and the permission alone.

Any help/explination would be amazing please.

Comment: Please post your model/entity classes. And also, what version of Entity Framework Core are you using?

Comment: How about `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermissionEntity>(O =>
        {
            O.HasKey(a => new { a.RoleId, a.PermissionId });
            O.HasOne(rp => rp.Role)
             .WithMany(b => b.RolePermissionEnties)
             .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.RoleId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            O.HasOne(rp => rp.Permission)
                .WithMany(c => c.RolePermissionEnties)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PermissionId);
        });
```

Delete role:
//Will delete the relevant data in the Role and the joining table.

```
var role = _context.RoleEntity.Single(c => c.Id == 2);
 _context.Remove(role);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

Delete joining table(Assumption 1 and 1 have a relationship):
//Will only delete the joining table.

```
var rolepermission= _context.RolePermissionEntity.Where(o => o.RoleEntityId == 1&&o.PermissionEntityId==1).FirstOrDefault();
_context.Remove(rolepermission);
_context.SaveChanges();
```